# JQuery: How to assign 'data-content' to equal contents of element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**Issue Background**

I'm trying to add a popover to every element with class `.param-value`. I want to do this via JQuery to make it more DRY.

**Issue**

How can I make the `data-content` attribute equal to the content of the element?

For example

```html
<p class="param-value" [...] data-content="Example Data 1">Example Data 1</p>
```

**What I've tried**

I have tried to use `$(this).html()` but as this is not an event handler I believe cannot pull this information.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="param-row row">
    <div class="col-3"><p class="param-name">Example Label 1</p></div>
    <div class="col-3"><p class="param-value">Example Data 1</p></div>
    <div class="col-3"><p class="param-name">Example Label 2</p></div>
    <div class="col-3"><p class="param-value">Example Data 2</p></div>
</div>
<div class="param-row row">
    <div class="col-3"><p class="param-name">Example Label 3</p></div>
    <div class="col-3"><p class="param-value">Example Data 3</p></div>
    <div class="col-3"><p class="param-name">Example Label 4</p></div>
    <div class="col-3"><p class="param-value">Example Data 4</p></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```js
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({'trigger':'hover'})
})

$('.param-value').attr('data-container','body')
$('.param-value').attr('data-toggle','popover')
$('.param-value').attr('data-placement','bottom')
$('.param-value').attr('data-html','true')
$('.param-value').attr('data-content',$(this).html())
```

**JSFIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/jx0csyLu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a [function](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) as a second parameter to the `attr` method and inside that function `$(this)` will be a reference to the current element and then you can just use `$(this).html()`

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    'trigger': 'hover'
  })
})

$('.param-value').attr('data-container', 'body')
$('.param-value').attr('data-toggle', 'popover')
$('.param-value').attr('data-placement', 'bottom')
$('.param-value').attr('data-html', 'true')
$('.param-value').attr('data-content', function() {
  return $(this).html()
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="param-row row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <p class="param-name">Example Label 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <p class="param-value">Example Data 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <p class="param-name">Example Label 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <p class="param-value">Example Data 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="param-row row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <p class="param-name">Example Label 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <p class="param-value">Example Data 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <p class="param-name">Example Label 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <p class="param-value">Example Data 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with JQuery's `each()`. Like so:

```js
$('.param-value').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-content',$(this).html())
})
```

If there is a more elegant solution, please let me know.